# How to remove a "zombie" network printer connection in c#?

Tags: c#, printing, wmi, access-denied, network-printers

I'm trying to delete a network printer that was removed from the printserver.

I'm using this code for deleting installed printers:

```
    public void unmapPrinter()
{
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath, options);
    scope.Connect();
    ManagementClass win32Printer = new ManagementClass("Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectCollection printers = win32Printer.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)
    {
        printer.Delete();
    }
}
```

This works well with normal printers, but there is one that was removed from the printerserver that return me "Access Denied". Some one know this problem?

Even windows can uninstal that printer, when i try to delete that from "Printers and Hardware" it tell me that the printer is in warning.

Comment: How about run it as administrator

Comment: It's already running as administrator